# vue-treeselect "Unhandled error during execution of watcher getter "

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Unable to bind value to list Vue3 Treeselect ([vue3-treeselect](https://github.com/megafetis/vue3-treeselect)). The problem occurs when setting (valueConsistsOf: "LEAF_PRIORITY"). Can you tell me what the reason is.

Working code here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bird-9i0qg3?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:228-341).

But when I run it on PC - I get the error:

[image: 1]

the code is exactly the same